# How dangerous is it to microwave melamine?

Tags: food-safety, chemical, poison

I've just eaten a meal off a melamine plate without knowing it. The food started frozen, so the plate went in the microwave several times in 30-second intervals.

I see plenty of sources saying "don't do that," but not a single one telling me if I'm going to get sick.

Comment: This is a question for cooking as the danger is to your plates.

Comment: This question belongs to cooking.se as it's not health related

Comment: What was the meal?

Answer (score 1):

FDA data https://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm199525.htm suggests there is increased migration of melamine into food at temps above 160'F but seems to take time to accumulate.  The level that leads to toxicity is estimated through risk assessment.  It seems toxicity is rare but can be severe:

> Products with melamine contamination above the levels noted in FDA’s
>   risk assessment may put people at risk of conditions such as kidney
>   stones and kidney failure, and of death. Signs of melamine poisoning
>   may include irritability, blood in urine, little or no urine, signs of
>   kidney infection, and / or high blood pressure.

No one here can tell you if you're going to get sick.  If you are worried or see concerning signs/symptoms, see a doctor.